# How to correctly use the Mean-Field Approximation to simplify a Commutation Relation in Excitonic Physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, commutator, approximations, many-body, mean-field-theory

I am following the work in 'Theoretical Methods for Excitonic Physics in 2D Materials'[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.12010).
They are aiming to derive the BSE equation for exciton physics. I am however stuck on the use of the Mean-field approximation they use and how they then obtain.

For the interaction Hamiltonian they have:$$\begin{array}{l}
H_{int}=\frac{1}{2 A} \sum_\lambda \sum_{\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{k}_3, \mathbf{k}_4} V_{\mathbf{q}} F_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4}\left(\mathbf{k}_3, \mathbf{k}_4, \mathbf{q}\right) c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} c_{\mathbf{k}_4 \lambda_4}
\end{array}
$$
They take the commutation relation of $H_{int}$ with the creation operator of an exciton which can be listed as:$$
b_\nu^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\phi(\mathbf{k})c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k},c}c_{\mathbf{k},v}
$$
The commutation relation can be calculated through standard commuation and anti-commuation relations to obtain:$$
\begin{array}{l}
{\left[c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} c_{\mathbf{k}_4 \lambda_4}, c_{\mathbf{k}, c}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\right]} \\
=c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} c_{\mathbf{k}, v} \delta_{\mathbf{k}_4, \mathbf{k}} \boldsymbol{\delta}_{\lambda_4, c} \\
\quad-c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_4 \lambda_4} c_{\mathbf{k}, v} \delta_{\mathbf{k}_3, \mathbf{k}} \boldsymbol{\delta}_{\lambda_3, c} \\
\quad+c_{\mathbf{k}, c}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} c_{\mathbf{k}_4 \lambda_4} \delta_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{k}} \boldsymbol{\delta}_{\lambda_2, v} \\
\quad-c_{\mathbf{k}, c}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} c_{\mathbf{k}_4 \lambda_4} \delta_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{k}} \boldsymbol{\delta}_{\lambda_1, v}
\end{array}
$$
Then as they use the mean-filed approximation the first term can be written as:$$
\begin{aligned}
c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} c_{\mathbf{k}, v} \approx & \left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\right\rangle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} \\
& +c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3}\right\rangle \\
& -\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3}\right\rangle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v} \\
& -c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3}\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\right\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
Which when they do this approximation for all terms that can rewrite the full commutation as:$$
\begin{aligned}
{\left[\hat{H}_{\mathrm{i} n t}, b_\nu^{\dagger}\right]=} & -\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{p}} \frac{\phi_\nu(\mathbf{p})}{A^{3 / 2}} V_{\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{p}} F_{c, v, v, c}(\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{k}-\mathbf{p}) c_{\mathbf{k}, c}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k} v} \\
& -\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{p}} \frac{\phi_\nu(\mathbf{p})}{A^{3 / 2}} V_{\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{p}} F_{v, c, v, c}(\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{k}-\mathbf{p}) c_{\mathbf{p}, c}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{p}, v} \\
& +\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{p}} \frac{\phi_\nu(\mathbf{k})}{A^{3 / 2}} V_{\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k}} F_{v, v, v, v}(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{k}, \mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k}) c_{\mathbf{k}, c}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}
\end{aligned}
$$
I am unsure how the last step is obtained. I have followed through with the approximations similar to that of the one above for the other three terms but am unable to see the continuation to obtain the three-term expression of the commutation as listed above.

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.12010):Quintela, M. F. M., Henriques, J. C., Tenório, L. G., & Peres, N. M. (2022). Theoretical methods for excitonic physics in 2D materials. physica status solidi (b), 259(7), 2200097. (link to paper on [Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.12010))

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of contributions, so I will try to show how to handle only one part of it and hope that it will help you to deal with all others. So, let us look at the first part of the commutator:
$$
c_{k_4+q \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{k_3-q \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{k_3 \lambda_3} c_{kv} \delta_{k_4 k} \delta_{\lambda_4 c}
$$
This part will be summed over all combinations of $\lambda$ (each can be from conduction or valence band, so in two-band case $\lambda \in \{ c, v\}$) and also over $q, k_3,k_4, k$ where $k_3, k_4$ have meaning of the initial momentums of electron and hole constituting the exciton, $q$ is transferred momentum between two interacting particles, $k$ is momentum of an exciton (should be close to zero if the exciton is excited by light). In the sum $\lambda_4$ will be replaced by $c$, $k_4$ will be replaced by $k$. Let us look then at the mean-field expression, using this replacement:
\begin{aligned}
c_{\mathbf{k}_4+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} c_{\mathbf{k}, v} \approx & \left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\right\rangle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3} \\
& +c_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3}\right\rangle \\
& -\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3}\right\rangle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v} \\
& -c_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3}\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}_3-\mathbf{q} \lambda_2}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\right\rangle
\end{aligned}
$c_k$ are one-particle electron states.  If these states have different band index of different momentum, then the average of the product of these states is zero as they are orthogonal to each other. For this reason, e.g., for third term $\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}_3 \lambda_3}\right\rangle$ to be not zero the condition $k_3=k+q$ is required. This condition gives limitations to the initial momentum of electron and is unnatural. It is so restricting that the part containing this average should be dropped. In the same way we get rid of the forth term. At the same time in the first term we see $\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q} \lambda_1}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k}, v}\right\rangle$ with corresponding condition $k+q=k$ with the condition $q=0$. It is an ok condition as $V_q$ gives its most prominent contribution for $q=0$. Also we get $\lambda_1 = v$ and then the average will be just $1$ as the norm of the state. If $\lambda_4 = c$ then $\lambda_3 = v$ corresponds to initial state with electron and hole constituting an exciton. The remaining $\lambda_2$ then should be $c$ for the final state also to be an exciton. This gives in the sum:
$$
F_{vcvc} (k_3, k) c_{k_3 c}^{\dagger} c_{k_3 v}
$$
The product of operators after summation gives $b^{\dagger}$. However, as it does not have $k$ in it, it will be summed separately from $\phi(k)$. For this reason action of this term on $\phi(k)$ is actually just a multiplication, which accounts for some constant energy shift in the spectrum. Let us now look at the second term. There under condition $q=0$ we have the average non-zero when $\lambda_2=\lambda_3$. As $\lambda_4=c$, $\lambda_3=v$, then $\lambda_2=v$ and finally $\lambda_1=c$. The corresponding term:
$$
F_{cvvc} (k_3,k) c_{kc}^{\dagger} c_{kv}
$$
The product of operators here depends on $k$ and therefore will have non-trivial effect on $\phi(k)$. The corresponding form factor $F_{cvvc}$ means that to calculate matrix of interaction we need to multiply $V_{q}$ by $\langle c k | c k' \rangle \langle v k' | v k \rangle $ where $q=k'-k$. The averages here are not zero despite they correspond to different momentums: the reason is that single-particle hamiltonian itself depends on $k$, so these are eigenvectors of different matrices. The remaining 3 parts of the commutator should be somehow similar. Hope it helps.